# iPhone Sqlite, Getting duplicates while fetching the data from database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am using the `sqlite` database for one of my projects. I am using the following query, but when I execute the query I'm getting duplicates.

```
SELECT * FROM 
lcs_mobile_class_folder_content,    lcs_mobile_assignment,       lcs_mobile_quiz 
WHERE
 ( lcs_mobile_class_folder_content.folder_id = '70c12fcd-d0cb-4243-95ad-1979f90c8ba7' 
AND 
(lcs_mobile_class_folder_content.class_content_id =  ( lcs_mobile_quiz.quiz_id)))
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the duplicates even though `quiz_id` is the primary key for the `lcs_mobile_quiz` table?

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple `lcs_mobile_class_folder_content` records that match one `lcs_mobile_quiz` record, you will get multiple result records.

Furhtermore, there is no filter or join on the `lcs_mobile_assignment` table, so all the other results will end up duplicated for *each* `lcs_mobile_assignment` record.